# Sendkey function works in line by line debug mode but not when I run the full code

Tags: excel, vba, sendkeys, attachmate-extra

This one is bizarre. Essentially I have a system that pulls up a DOS program (great start right??) to export data from it. I am having my macro send the keys to navigate and then copy and paste the data from the screens. When I test the function going line by line with  it works perfect. However, when I run the full command it breaks. Am I missing something obvious here??

```
    Sub Import_Account_Cusip()  'Completes search by Account and Cusip
    
    Dim LastPageCheck As String
    Dim AccountCheck As String
    Dim AcctNumber As String
    Dim iRow As Integer
    Dim AcctType As String
    Dim Cusip As String
    Dim FromDate As String
    Dim ToDate As String
    
    FromDate = Range("C25").Value       'This assigns the from date in the search filter
    ToDate = Range("G25").Value         'This assigns the to date in the filter
    
    
    Worksheets("LTXN Data").Visible = True
    Worksheets("LTXN Formatting").Visible = True
    Worksheets("Definitions").Visible = True
    
    Sheets("Launch").Activate
    AcctNumber = Range("C23").Value     'This assigns the value of the Account Number search
    Cusip = Range("G23").Value         'This assigns the value of the Cusip search
    
    
    ' ******** set session to bluezone **********
    
        Set Sess0 = CreateObject("BluezoneDOSSystem.WhllObj")
        Sess0.Connect ("")         'Connect to bluezone session 1 - internally called A
        
    ' *****************************************************************************
         
        HostSettleTime = 200        'set 200 milliseconds to wait for session to respond
    
        Sess0.WaitReady 10, HostSettleTime
    
    
    '--------------RESET VARIABLES-------------------
    AccountCheck = ""
    LastPageCheck = ""
    
    Sess0.SendKeys ("<clear>")
    Sess0.WaitReady 10, HostSettleTime
    Sess0.SendKeys ("LTXN ") & AcctNumber
    Sess0.SendKeys ("<Enter>")
    Sess0.WaitReady 10, HostSettleTime
    
    Sess0.SendKeys ("<Tab>")                    'This is the search filter for CUSIP
    Sess0.SendKeys ("<Tab>")
    Sess0.SendKeys ("CUS")
    Sess0.SendKeys Cusip
    Sess0.SendKeys ("<Enter>")
    Sess0.WaitReady 10, HostSettleTime
    
    Sess0.SendKeys ("<F12>")                    
    'This is the date filter this is where the code 
'is breaking as well because this basically 
'pulls up a filter menu where you have to tab 
'5 times to get to date input. 
'However it seems to skip the 
'next 6 lines of code. Any ideas???
    
    Sess0.SendKeys ("<Tab>")
    Sess0.SendKeys ("<Tab>")
    Sess0.SendKeys ("<Tab>")
    Sess0.SendKeys ("<Tab>")
    Sess0.SendKeys ("<Tab>")
    Sess0.SendKeys FromDate
    Sess0.SendKeys ToDate
    Sess0.SendKeys ("<Enter>")
    Sess0.WaitReady 10, HostSettleTime
    
    Sess0.ReadScreen AccountCheck, 24, 4, 1                    
'looks for account number not found language
    
    If LCase(AccountCheck) = "account number not found" Then    
'using lower case to reduce case sensitivity
        MsgBox ("Account Number Not Found. Please Double Check Account Number.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Sess0.ReadScreen NoDataChk, 1, iRow, 4          
'check for no data in at all
    If NoDataChk = " " Then
        MsgBox ("There appears to be no transactions.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    
    Sheets("LTXN Data").Activate          
  'set active WS to LTXN Data
    Range("A2").Name = "Next_Line"         
 'Starts row A2 as starting row in spreadsheet
    
    Do Until LCase(LastPageCheck) = "last page"    
'Main Loop, do until it sees Last Page
    
    
    
        For iRow = 10 To 22                  'start Sub Loop
            Sess0.ReadScreen NoDataChk, 1, iRow, 4          
'check for no data in row-slight variation of above routine
            If NoDataChk = " " Then GoTo 1000
            
            
            Sess0.ReadScreen AcctType, 1, iRow, 2           
'start read section, need to double check capture 
'strings and look for unusual cases with long sym, high qtys, etc.
            Sess0.ReadScreen EffDate, 8, iRow, 4
            Sess0.ReadScreen TranType, 6, iRow, 13
            Sess0.ReadScreen TickerSym, 5, iRow, 19
            Sess0.ReadScreen Quantity, 14, iRow, 25
            Sess0.ReadScreen SNoS, 1, iRow, 39
            Sess0.ReadScreen TranDesc, 24, iRow, 41
            Sess0.ReadScreen TrnTotal, 15, iRow, 65
            Sess0.ReadScreen TrnType, 1, iRow, 80
            
            Range("Next_Line").Value = AcctType                 'filling in spreadsheet rows
            Range("Next_Line").Offset(0, 1).Value = EffDate
            Range("Next_Line").Offset(0, 2).Value = TranType
            Range("Next_Line").Offset(0, 3).Value = TickerSym
            Range("Next_Line").Offset(0, 4).Value = Quantity
            Range("Next_Line").Offset(0, 5).Value = SNoS
            Range("Next_Line").Offset(0, 6).Value = TranDesc
            Range("Next_Line").Offset(0, 7).Value = TrnTotal
            Range("Next_Line").Offset(0, 8).Value = TrnType
           
            Range("Next_Line").Offset(1, 0).Name = "Next_Line"  
'sets Next Line to next row first cell
                
        Next iRow                            'next subloop
    
    
    1000
        Sess0.SendKeys ("<PF8>")                 'Main Loop page forward
        Sess0.WaitReady 10, HostSettleTime
        Sess0.ReadScreen LastPageCheck, 9, 4, 1 
'Main Loop look for last page language. 
'might need to be move depending on second f8 press needed or not. 
'if not then move to beginning after Do statement
    Loop                                    'Main Loop
    
    MsgBox ("LTXN Transaction Macro has completed gathering information from Account " + AcctNumber)    'Closing message
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: If you insist on using sendkeys, I highly doubt you're giving your computer enough time to keep up. Depending on what you're typing this into, you might need to give it a bit of a break even in between tabs. Sendkeys method is notoriously unreliable.

Comment: [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) might be a more robust way to interact with that old app

Comment: @CameronCritchlow I am absolutely willing to do it another way. I am pretty new to this so if you have guidance I am happy to hear it. The trouble with the old app is I dont know of another way to navigate it.

Comment: Does whatever database your accessing have any kind of api? Does that program have any way to schedule exports? If not, Sendkeys might be the easiest way... just try putting a full second wait (or more depending on load times) between every action... then slowly reducing it until you find the break points.    I have one export series I have to do with sendkeys... the only program i couldn't find a way around... and I found a vba function to return pixel colour on a pixel on the screen. i use that to check if page fully loaded.

Comment: This is not the VBA.SendKeys. This is a "proprietary" SendKeys of the App. I worked with Attachmate Extra, about 30 years (!), that has the same objects/methods presented in this code (Sess0, SendKeys, WaitReady, etc.) Minor differences in command names. For instance, this piece of the code: Sess0.ReadScreen EffDate, 8, iRow, 4 reads in position  column 8 and row iRow of the screen, four digits. What you may replace on the code is these "tab tab tab tab tab" wich probably is not properly processed in time on the server side. Use SendKeys directly to where the last "tab" is set (Column+Line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To @ALeXcel's credit, this is absolutely Attachmate Extra. I was able to fix it with the following code:

```
 Sess0.SendKeys ("<F12>")                    'This is the date filter
Sess0.WaitReady 10, HostSettleTime
Sess0.SendKeys ("<Tab>")
Sess0.WaitReady 10, HostSettleTime
Sess0.SendKeys ("<Tab>")
Sess0.WaitReady 10, HostSettleTime
Sess0.SendKeys ("<Tab>")
Sess0.WaitReady 10, HostSettleTime
Sess0.SendKeys ("<Tab>")
Sess0.WaitReady 10, HostSettleTime
Sess0.SendKeys ("<Tab>")
Sess0.SendKeys FromDate
Sess0.WaitReady 10, HostSettleTime
Sess0.SendKeys ToDate
Sess0.WaitReady 10, HostSettleTime
Sess0.SendKeys ("<Enter>")
Sess0.WaitReady 10, HostSettleTime
```